# how to update in elastic search based on a string field

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a bank accounts dataset which have the fields account number,state,firstname,lastname.iam writing the following command to update all the firstname records of the customers from state CA to antony.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_update_by_query?pretty' -d '{
 "query" : {
  "term" : {"state":"CA"}
 },
 "script" : {
  "inline" : "ctx._source.firstname = a",
  "params" : {
   "a" : "antony"
  },
  "lang" : "groovy"
 }
}'
```

result:

{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 0,
  "updated" : 0,
  "batches" : 0,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}

None of the records are getting updated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of ES are you running? And are you sure you have [enabled dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)?

Comment: version 2.3.4. and yes, i enabled dynamic scripting

Comment: is the `state` field `analyzed` or `not_analyzed`? i.e. how many documents do you get if you run the query separately?

Comment: i did not mention anything while indexing and there are 8 documents with state CA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `state` field is `analyzed` (by default), you need to use a `match` query instead of a `term` one (or keep the `term` query but lowercase `CA` to `ca`)

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/bank/_update_by_query?pretty' -d '{
 "query" : {
  "match" : {"state":"CA"}
 },
 "script" : {
  "inline" : "ctx._source.firstname = a",
  "params" : {
   "a" : "antony"
  },
  "lang" : "groovy"
 }
}'
```

Comment: How to replace the whole `_source` field to a new value based on the match query?

Comment: @AbhijithS feel free to ask a new question explaining your issue.

Comment: @Val Done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50743317/update-the-whole-source-field-based-on-particular-search-query

Answer (score 0):

If somebody wants to do this just simply through Kibana just use this script as the sample to add in Dev Tools redactor in Kibana, here you are:

```
POST persons/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "term": {"person_id": 249917}
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.dri_for_buyers = 4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to update the mapping for your filed state then u first need to delete the mapping and recreate again in 2.x because while updating it will not update your mapping properly in Es 2.2.

**As per Elatic search document** : 
  **We can update a mapping to add a new field, but we can’t change an existing field from analyzed to not_analyzed.**

First you can take the backup of your mapping. then delete it using below link.
curl -XDELETE 'http://host.sachin.com:9999/ecmviews/?pretty'

after deleting  the mapping, u can you the same backup mapping and update the state filed like below:
          "state" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },

and update mapping json using below command:
curl -XPUT 'http://host.sachin.com:9999/ecmviews' -d '{
your mapping json without curl backets
}
. it will update the mapping with ack:true as response.
after updating the mapping you can try your query. it will work.

Comment: This appears to be self-promotion, which is considered spam when not done within the guidelines. Please see: [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Please add code and errors as text [using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).