# Elasticsearch update the whole `_source` field based on search query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

```
"_source": {
         "id": "5b1676493d21784208c36041",
         "label": "name",
         "properties": {
           "name": "patrick"
         },
         "updatedAt": 1528259039542
       }
```

I want to update this document based on `id` (not `_id`) with a new document.

Something like this:

```
    "_source": {
             "dataSource": "ELASTIC",
             "entity": "vertices",
             "label": "vertices",
             "id": "5b1676493d21784208c36041",
             "properties": {
                     "name": "patrick"
                  },
             "updatedAt": 1528259039542
           }
```

elasticsearch version: 6.2, ES Java api: 6.2

Comment: Since there is no such thing as an update in a search engine anyway, just delete the old document, then add the new one. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html may help.

Comment: Yeah @Harald I thought the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html), basically like this:

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "id": "5b1676493d21784208c36041"
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source = params",
    "params": {
       "dataSource": "ELASTIC",
       "entity": "vertices",
       "label": "vertices"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE: Using the Java API**

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("dataSource", "ELASTIC");
params.put("entity", "vertices");
params.put("label", "vertices");

UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder updateByQuery = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client);
updateByQuery.source("index")
    .filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("id", "5b1676493d21784208c36041"))
    .size(1000)
    .script(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source.putAll(params)", params));
BulkByScrollResponse response = updateByQuery.get();
```

More details on using the [UpdateByQuery Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-update-by-query.html) and [Java high level rest client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-update.html)

Comment: It's the name of the scripting language used in the script present in the  second parameter

Comment: Please update your question with the results... more legible than here

Comment: Can you provide a meaningful portion of the stacktrace ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172750/discussion-between-abhijith-s-and-val).

Comment: `"ctx._source = params"` This also is not supporting

Comment: I'm curious to know what your `introspect()` method does... Can you create a simple HashMap like I did in my example and try it out? Start simple and then iterate.

Comment: when I tried using HashMap as you said "ctx._source = params" is not supporting

Comment: Setting ctx.op to any other value generates an error. Setting any other field in ctx generates an error. from the es documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-update-by-query.html

Comment: Small change @Val `.script(new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source = params", params));`

Comment: You're right, I've inverted the "painless" and the code. I don't think that's a reason for downvoting, though. I've updated the code. Works better now?

Comment: No, Actually my requirement is different this is creating a field `ctx` in  `_source`

Comment: What the script does is replace all fields of the `_source` with the ones present in `params`, which is what you asked for. `ctx._source` is the way to access the original source document and we assign it the params values

Comment: hey @Val can you pleas check my updated question? That is what my requirement.

Comment: You should have created a new question as now all the comments are out of sync with the question and answer :-(

Comment: Why can't we delete the comments and you can edit your answer corresponding to my updated question right?

Comment: Because I prefer spending time helping people than curating comments based on edited questions ;-)

Comment: Nice :P . btw I tried by searching with Id and updating but with 2 api(get and put) calls, Actually my intution says this can be solved using single script query OR in a single api call.

Comment: Simply replace the script by this one `ctx._source.putAll(params)`, it will keep the original source, but overwrite it with all fields present in params

Comment: Getting closer @Val 
 "_source": {
         "ctx": {
           "_routing": null,
           "_parent": null,
           "_index": "vertices",
           "_type": "vertices",
           "_id": "AeZz82MBrouOs8r6VAyE",
           "_version": 1
         },
         "id": "5b1676493d21784208c36041",
         "label": "updatedLabel",
         "properties": {
           "name": "sheji"
         },
         "updatedAt": 1528797832451
       } . But I don't want that `ctx`field. Can I remove that?

Comment: Anyway update your answer @Val I will accept the answer. :)

Comment: let me figure out why first

Comment: In the future, please make sure to not modify the question in such a way that the posted answers don't make sense anymore.

Comment: Sure @Val I ll definitely take that into consideration

Answer (score 1):

`"ctx._source.putAll(params)"` was a nice try, but unfortunately it moves all existing fields under `_source.ctx`.

So, the following works for me (ES 6.1):

```
"for (k in params.keySet()){if (!k.equals('ctx')){ctx._source.put(k, params.get(k))}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jetnet for providing an idea to loop through all the entries in the map. When I used the script, it was still replacing the entire object, so had to adapt it as per the below to preserve the fields not supplied during an update operation. For context, if I first insert a document that has three objects each with 2 fields, if I then updated that document with the same 3 objects, but with 1 field each, the output is that I end up with a document with 3 objects each with 1 field instead of 3 objects with 2 fields each as I had originally.

I had to adapt @jetnet's script to give me the desired outcome of not overwriting object properties

```
POST /transaction_index/_update/33384637-3137-3132-5543-31304c4c3151
{
   "script": {
      "source": "if (ctx._source.Metadata == null || params.Metadata.Version >= ctx._source.Metadata.Version) { for (k in params.keySet()){ if (ctx._source[k] != null) { ctx._source[k].putAll(params.get(k)) } else { ctx._source.put(k, params.get(k)) } } } else { ctx.op = 'none' }",
      "params": {
         "Transaction": {
            "TransactionId": "33384637-3137-3132-5543-31304c4c3151",
            "TransactionKey": "Key1"
         },
         "Message": {
            "MessageId": "505a5953-374a-385a-4a48-52353549445a",
            "Context": "This is a test context"
         },
         "MessageDefinition": {
            "MessageDefinitionId": "a1c05e06-fa6b-40ce-992f-d083ff6c0243",
            "Code": 1010101010
         },
         "Metadata": {
            "Version": 1,
            "CreateTime": "2020-09-04T14:27:51.1986439+01:00",
            "IsLatest": true,
            "IsDummy": false,
            "VersionString": "20200903111111"
         }
    }
 },
 "scripted_upsert": true,
 "upsert": {}
}
```